# Can't compile the Angular application with Ivy enabled

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-forms, angular-ivy

I cloned my angular application from remote and installed the dependencies. Then I tried to build an application locally using ng serve command which threw me this error as attached in the Error Image.

**Error Image**
[image]

I was able to bypass this by adding the below code in my tsconfig file. But I still couldn't find the reason behind it. Please let me know What's going wrong and thanks in advance.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": 
{
  "enableIvy": false
}
```

For reference, I am adding my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.6",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.0.16",
    "aws-amplify-angular": "^5.0.16",
    "mat-progress-buttons": "^9.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try deleting the node_modules and package_lock and doing npm install again

Comment: seems like the material forms has not been updated

Comment: Yes, I tried deleting node_modules and package_lock but still no luck. @SachithRukshan

Comment: Try
npm cache clean --force

Comment: Yep, I tried still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

please follow up with [this issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4681) and check as this is a currently open ticket in amplify-js Github Repo. This seems to be the cause that gives that error.